# How to Get A Company Financials in to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get a specific value from a public company's balance sheet into Google Spreadsheet to better analyze the company financials. I want to add the ticker in one of the cells and via a formula, I will get the *Total Current Assets* for example.

Is there a way to it?

The main issue is that the data is populated after the page is being rendered, so even if I use the IMPORTHTML and set the right XPath I am getting `Imported content is empty`. It because the value is since it is being fetched on the on a later script.

I found [this](https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs/) service which provides the company's financials in a JSON and CSV formats, but I dont know how to parse it on the googlesheet.

Should be something that someone already solved.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your financial information coming from? Accounting software, bank account, etc? Please provide more details.

Comment: If you are able to get JSON data from your source company, there are lots of questions and answers on that subject on SO, which seem to help solve how to parse data into Google Sheets.  But CSV data might be even simpler.